# Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python: App Engine, python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a website on Google App Engine Standard Environment with Flask. Python 3.9.

I'm also using Firestore(Native Mode):

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
cred = credentials.Certificate("*****.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

Locally everything works fine, but after deploying I get the following errors:

1. ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
2. ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/workspace/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/**init**.py)

I installed **grpcio**, **google-cloud-core**, **google-cloud-firestore**, but still have this problem.

Comment: Show us your requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

That error gives the impression that the google-cloud-firestore is not in your requirements.txt file and so was not installed when you run your App on Production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but google-cloud-firestore in requirements.txt:
...
firebase-admin==5.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
google==3.0.0
google-api-core==2.1.1
google-api-python-client==2.26.1
google-api-python-client-py3==1.2
google-auth==2.3.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-cloud-core==2.1.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.3.4
google-cloud-storage==1.42.3
google-crc32c==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==2.0.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
grpcio==1.41.0
...